# Why is my perlin noise producing values that are waaay outside the expected range, and producing non-repeating tiles with hard edges?

Tags: php, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

So, I wrote my php perlin noise implementation (code at the end) based on https://flafla2.github.io/2014/08/09/perlinnoise.html, and I'm getting strange results.

To summarise, here is a picture of the grayscale for x and y between 0 and 5 obtained by mapping each value between 0 and 1 to a value between 0x0 and 0xFF, and repeating it thrice. Also the value is truncated just to be on the safe side.

[image: perlin weirdness]

The first thing one notices about this supposed grayscale is that it is *not* in fact grayscale. The colours are valid because of the truncation. However, the colourfull and white patches *exist* because the values are not between 0 and 1, but (in this case) between `-21.807741342341`,and `20.055290825771` (obtained from the same program).

Based on what I have seen while debugging this thing previously, I'd guess the colours are over 1, and the whites are negative (also, when I add an `abs()` to the code, I get rid of all pure white areas).

From what I understand of perlin noise, it should be continuous. Not with these lines drawn wherever x or y is an exact unit.

Also, in the comments of the tutorial, it says that the values returned should never exceed the [0,1] boundary. Evidently, it is. What is going on here? Not that I dislike these patterns or anything, but I think that using a working perlin noise one can probably get something similar.

Note: the image is pixely because I generate it in what is probably the most stupid and convoluted way possible. Please don't complain.

```php
<?php

class perlin{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->p=array_merge($this->permutation,$this->permutation);
        //print_r($this->p);
    }

    private $permutation=array(93, 127, 136, 113, 54, 147, 1, 165, 82, 43, 7, 125, 149, 244, 192, 100, 48, 39, 96, 98, 255, 60, 22, 158, 171, 137, 23, 72, 142, 166, 11, 94, 92, 87, 139, 247, 111, 236, 61, 188, 86, 250, 151, 9, 14, 90, 8, 124, 180, 179, 157, 17, 141, 209, 35, 242, 42, 184, 186, 172, 21, 215, 162, 227, 74, 121, 177, 253, 214, 220, 66, 230, 109, 46, 239, 119, 175, 238, 19, 6, 95, 15, 229, 190, 226, 26, 88, 182, 106, 76, 27, 49, 212, 213, 25, 89, 56, 219, 205, 164, 83, 38, 146, 5, 102, 170, 115, 181, 103, 228, 211, 31, 155, 197, 232, 204, 52, 199, 173, 148, 101, 85, 153, 156, 3, 224, 47, 33, 208, 150, 114, 116, 129, 145, 50, 160, 183, 140, 36, 217, 185, 233, 132, 107, 135, 75, 221, 191, 223, 81, 32, 10, 243, 18, 65, 246, 248, 78, 176, 225, 131, 55, 29, 80, 99, 16, 71, 112, 163, 62, 123, 51, 195, 251, 178, 67, 44, 105, 159, 30, 104, 174, 4, 152, 57, 133, 252, 45, 120, 256, 207, 70, 202, 201, 68, 189, 84, 169, 53, 254, 168, 12, 59, 249, 206, 63, 200, 128, 37, 77, 108, 64, 28, 122, 196, 167, 91, 117, 231, 187, 34, 69, 41, 110, 241, 40, 154, 237, 73, 143, 58, 245, 20, 234, 235, 222, 97, 210, 193, 161, 203, 216, 118, 24, 126, 194, 79, 218, 2, 13, 138, 130, 134, 240, 144, 198);
    //generated by seq 1 256|shuf|sed 's/$/,/g'|tr '\n' ' '

    public $repeat=0;

    private $p=array();

    private function inc($num){
        $num++;
        if($this->repeat>0){
            $num%=$this->repeat;
        }
        return $num;
    }

    private function fade(float $t){
        return $t*$t*$t*($t*($t*6+15)+10);
    }

    public function perlin(float $x,float $y,float $z){
        if($this->repeat>0){
            $x=$x%$this->repeat;
            $y=$y%$this->repeat;
            $z=$z%$this->repeat;
        }
        $xi=(int)($x) & 255;
        $yi=(int)($y) & 255;
        $zi=(int)($z) & 255;
        $xf=$x-(int)($x);
        $yf=$y-(int)($y);
        $zf=$z-(int)($z);

        //echo "$xi $yi $zi $xf $yf $zf<br>\n\n";

        $u=$this->fade($xf);
        $v=$this->fade($yf);
        $w=$this->fade($zf);

        $aaa=$this->p[$this->p[$this->p[           $xi ]+           $yi ]+           $zi ];
        $aba=$this->p[$this->p[$this->p[           $xi ]+$this->inc($yi)]+           $zi ];
        $aab=$this->p[$this->p[$this->p[           $xi ]+           $yi ]+$this->inc($zi)];
        $abb=$this->p[$this->p[$this->p[           $xi ]+$this->inc($yi)]+$this->inc($zi)];
        $baa=$this->p[$this->p[$this->p[$this->inc($xi)]+           $yi ]+           $zi ];
        $bba=$this->p[$this->p[$this->p[$this->inc($xi)]+$this->inc($yi)]+           $zi ];
        $bab=$this->p[$this->p[$this->p[$this->inc($xi)]+           $yi ]+$this->inc($zi)];
        $bbb=$this->p[$this->p[$this->p[$this->inc($xi)]+$this->inc($yi)]+$this->inc($zi)];

        $x1=$this->lerp($this->grad($aaa,$xf,$yf,$zf),
                        $this->grad($baa,$xf-1,$yf,$zf),$u);
        $x2=$this->lerp($this->grad($aba,$xf,$yf-1,$zf),
                        $this->grad($bba,$xf-1,$yf-1,$zf),$u);
        $y1=$this->lerp($x1,$x2,$v);

        $x1=$this->lerp($this->grad($aab,$xf,$yf,$zf-1),
                        $this->grad($bab,$xf-1,$yf,$zf-1),$u);
        $x2=$this->lerp($this->grad($abb,$xf,$yf-1,$zf-1),
                        $this->grad($bbb,$xf-1,$yf-1,$zf-1),$u);
        $y2=$this->lerp($x1,$x2,$v);

        return ($this->lerp($y1,$y2,$w)+1)/2;
    }



    private function grad(int $hash,float $x,float $y,float $z){
        switch($hash & 0xF){
            case 0x0: return $x+$y;
            case 0x1: return -$x + $y;
            case 0x2: return  $x - $y;
            case 0x3: return -$x - $y;
            case 0x4: return  $x + $z;
            case 0x5: return -$x + $z;
            case 0x6: return  $x - $z;
            case 0x7: return -$x - $z;
            case 0x8: return  $y + $z;
            case 0x9: return -$y + $z;
            case 0xA: return  $y - $z;
            case 0xB: return -$y - $z;
            case 0xC: return  $y + $x;
            case 0xD: return -$y + $z;
            case 0xE: return  $y - $x;
            case 0xF: return -$y - $z;
            default: return 0;
        }
    }

    private function lerp(float $a,float $b,float $x){
        return $a+$x*($b-$a);
    }

}
?>
```

A minimal example of an illegal value:

```php
<?php 
require("perlin.php");
$noise=new perlin;

echo $noise->perlin(1.5,0.5,0);        //return 1.4375
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking why your perlin code returns values outside the range (0,1)? I also dont see what method you are using to generate the image with your perlin numbers?

Comment: @chiliNUT I'm asking why my perlin noise isn't behaving like perlin noise. As for the method, it is the most stupid way possible, but I outlined it in the second paragraph.

Comment: *"I'm asking why my perlin noise isn't behaving like perlin noise"*. What does that mean? How is it behaving vs how do you expect it to behave? *"As for the method, it is the most stupid way possible"* thats not what I'm asking about. The only code you provided that I can see is generating a number, the perlin noise, yet you refer to the graphic in your question several times but do not indicate how you generated it. You also said *"`// a minimal example of an illegal value`"*. Why is it illegal? Because it is out of range? What range should it be in?

Comment: @chiliNUT The title of the question summarises the problems perfectly. I also say what range I expect the values to  be between two or three times. The method of obtaining the colours for the graphic is explained in the paragraph preceding it. The exact method of obtaining it is completely irrelevant. I expect it to behave in a way not dissimilar to this: https://flafla2.github.io/img/2014-08-09-perlinnoise/logic04.png. It is not behaving like that, as seen in the provided image.

Comment: Thanks! I must have glossed over that.

Answer (score 1):

You flipped a sign in your `fade` function. You have *`6`**`+`**`15`* where it should be *`6`**`-`**`15`*.

> ```
> public static double fade(double t) {
>     return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);         // 6t^5 - 15t^4 + 10t^3
> }
> ```

After that change I get

```
$noise->perlin(1.5,0.5,0); // 0.5
```

Comment: @MarkGardner Did you get the same output as me for the perlin function, ie, `$noise->perlin(1.5,0.5,0) = 0.8125` or a different value? That sign error was the only difference I found when I compared your code to the website

Comment: I got 0.5, not 0.8125.

Comment: still going out of range, and the tiles are still there.